# JPA @ManyToMany associations seem to only be working 1 way

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got the following association defined:

```
public class Location
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="locations")
    private List<KMLFolder> kmlFolderList;

public class KMLFolder
...
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="LOCATION_KMLFOLDER",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="KMLFOLDER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
            )
    private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

Here is a unit test.  The first 3 assertions pass but the last one fails:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void thatFolderLocationAssociationTableIsWorking() {
    Location l1 = new DomesticLocation();
    l1.setDeptName("Test name 1");
    Location l2 = new DomesticLocation();
    l2.setDeptName("Test name 2");

    KMLFolder k1 = new KMLFolder();
    k1.setName("Test name 1");

    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    locations.add(l1);
    locations.add(l2);
    k1.setLocations(locations);

    kmlFolderServiceImpl.save(k1);

    assertEquals("Test name 1", kmlFolderServiceImpl.find(1L).getLocations().get(0).getDeptName());
    assertEquals("Test name 2", kmlFolderServiceImpl.find(1L).getLocations().get(1).getDeptName());
    assertNotNull(locationServiceImpl.findAll().get(0));

    //Failing Assertion
    assertNotNull(locationServiceImpl.find(1L).getKmlFolderList());

}
```

Any thoughts why this may not be persisting correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: I notice you explicitely save the `k1`, do you not need to do that aswell for the locations `l1, l2`?

Comment: My thought was the cascading would take care of that.  I tried with explicit saves of l1 and l2 before k2 with the same results I've described above.

Comment: You already asked this question, and I already answered, and you accepted the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976442/jpa-manytomany-not-persisting-in-assocation-table. The inverse side is ignored by Hibernate. You MUST populate the owner side, otherwise, for Hibernate, no association exists between the objects.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I applied that change.  The Association table is being created when I run the unit test.  However now I am unable to get the associated objects of the inverted class.

Answer (score 1):

All the code is executed inside a single transaction. The Hibernate session, and thus the first-level cache, is thus unique for all the code in the test. Your code initializes one side of the association without initializing the other. You thus create an incoherent object graph, that is stored in the first level cache.

When using Hibernate to load the entities using a finder, Hibernate returns the incoherent entities that are in the cache. If you had one transaction for saving, and another one to get back the entities, Hibernate would use a new, empty cache for the second transaction, and would populate the entities, in a coherent way, from the data found in the tables.

Comment: So because the whole test is annotated as @Transactional, Hibernate gets 'confused?'  Is there a way to test insert and finds in my scenario?

Comment: Hibernate isn't confused at all. It follows the rules, but you don't understand them. If your test aims at checking that the code can save and get what has been saved, then it does it fine. You simply must not expect Hibernate to fix all the incohrencies of your object tree while the object tree is in memory, in the cache.